# QT5 How to paint with two events?

Tags: qt, user-interface, events, qt5, media-player

I have a area shows waveform of a wave file.
I want that a line follow mouse moving like audio editor and this line's behavior is like progressbar when it is playing.
But there's only one paintEvent function, it works well when it is not playing, how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the `paintEvent` isn't meant to react to user interaction directly. You should handle interaction in relevant mouse/keyboard event handlers, and modify a data structure that describes what's to be shown. Before returning from the event handler, queue an update using `QWidget::update()`.

The `paintEvent` will be then called from the event loop, and should repaint the widget based on the updated data. Also don't forget that the `paintEvent` can be called at any time, and that you can paint on the widget only from within the `paintEvent`.

Comment: How to  call `repaint()` at same time?

Comment: @Asuka Why do you think that you want to call `repaint()`? You're supposed to call `update()`, it queues a repaint event, and eventually `QWidget::event` calls your reimplementation of `paintEvent`.